# hashset io java

Tags: java, io, hashset

Im working on the following question and think I am quite close to the answer. My issue is with the input as I am just getting used to standard java i/o.

> Print a count of the number of unique words entered by the user, followed by the words themselves.

**EDIT: Problem solved**

Code:

```
class Uniques { 

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String w = scanner.nextLine();

        String s[] = w.split(",");

        for(String place:s)
        hs.add(place);

    }
    System.out.println("There were " + hs.size() + 
                        " unique words, as follows:");
    for (String s: hs) 
            System.out.println(s);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String w = scanner.next();
```

You need to split the String `w` for `words`and then add them to `Set`.

Example:

```
String[] wordsArray = str.split(" ");


for(String word:wordsArray)
        {
            //add to set
        }
```

Comment: it might also help to do some basic stuff to flatten case and remove punctuation.

Comment: @Wug: I guess "flatten case" may depend on requirement. If professor wants to treat "Hi" different from "hi", then "flatten case" may cause issue.

Comment: An example or a link to one would be great, im self learning at the moment.

Comment: @Roddy I didnt tag it as that, Im teaching myself Java for an exam.

Comment: @thinksteep could you explain what 'for(String place:s)' is doing?

Comment: @Dave: Splits the string into words. for(String...) loops through the array. Java we call it as for-each loop

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
myString.split("\\s+");
```

to split the string into words delimited by all white space...